# creating dataframe by applying conditions to the date column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Available Dataframe :

```
Date_1         Type_1     Qty_1     Date_2         Type_2      Qty_2
29-12-2023       A          1       01-01-2024       B           2
29-12-2023       A          3       01-01-2024       B           4
30-12-2023       A          2       01-01-2024       B           3
30-12-2023       A          5       02-01-2024       B           5
31-12-2023       A          10      02-01-2024       B           6
31-12-2023       A          2       03-01-2024       B           1
01-01-2024       A          1       04-01-2023       B           2
```

i need to check Date_2 column and apply below condition:

if Date_2(first entry, no duplicates) column is Monday, i need to get the previous three days data from these columns [Type_1,Qty_1] appending it with current data i.e. [Type_2,Qty_2].
so the output data would look like :

```
Date            Type       Qty

29-12-2023       A          1 
29-12-2023       A          3
30-12-2023       A          2 
30-12-2023       A          5
31-12-2023       A          10
31-12-2023       A          2
01-01-2024       B          2
01-01-2024       B          4
01-01-2024       B          3
```

for other days, we just need to add previous days data with the current days data. for example :

```
Date            Type       Qty
01-01-2024       A          1
02-01-2024       B          5
02-01-2024       B          6
```

with these logic want to create the new dataframe.

i have initiated with below code but stuck inbetween :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
# Function to find previous three dates for a given date
def get_previous_three_dates(date):
    return [date - timedelta(days=i) for i in range(1, 4)]

#Function to get Type and Value for previous three dates if the given date is Monday
    def get_type_value_for_previous_dates(df, column_name):
        result = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row[column_name].weekday() == 0:  # Check if the date is Monday (Monday corresponds to 0)
                previous_dates = get_previous_three_dates(row[column_name])
                for prev_date in previous_dates:
                    # Check if the previous date exists in the DataFrame
                    if prev_date in df['Date_1'].values:
                        entry = df[df['Date_1'] == prev_date][['Type_1', 'Sales_1']].iloc[0].to_dict()
                        result.append({ 'Date': prev_date, 'Type': entry['Type_1'], 'Qty': entry['Sales_1']})
        return result
```

any leads will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to do some manual iteration and slicing here, though there may be a better solution using a `merge_asof` join followed by a filter.

Taking the data you supplied, I split the two subframes apart into `df_a` and `df_b`. This lets me index them separately and they become easier to query against.

Then I iterate over the unique chunks of `df_b` (which corresponds to the `"_2"` columns in the original frame). From there it's similar to the approach you had originally: check if the `date.weekday() == 0` and grab the appropriate number of days in the past from the other DataFrame `df_a`.

Finally I store each of these parts in a list and create a `label` variable to track all of the unique groupings individually.

```py
from io import StringIO
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

buffer = StringIO('''
Date_1         Type_1     Qty_1     Date_2         Type_2      Qty_2
29-12-2023       A          1       01-01-2024       B           2
29-12-2023       A          3       01-01-2024       B           4
30-12-2023       A          2       01-01-2024       B           3
30-12-2023       A          5       02-01-2024       B           5
31-12-2023       A          10      02-01-2024       B           6
31-12-2023       A          2       03-01-2024       B           1
01-01-2024       A          1       04-01-2023       B           2
''')

df = (
    pd.read_table(buffer, sep='\s+')
    .assign(
        Date_1=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['Date_1'], format='%d-%m-%Y'),
        Date_2=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['Date_2'], format='%d-%m-%Y'),
    )
)

df_a = (
    df.filter(regex='_1$')
    .rename(columns=lambda c: c.removesuffix('_1'))
    .set_index('Date')
)
df_b = (
    df.filter(regex='_2$')
    .rename(columns=lambda c: c.removesuffix('_2'))
    .set_index('Date')
)

chunks, labels = [], []
for i, (date, group) in enumerate(df_b.groupby('Date')):
    ndays = 3 if date.weekday() == 0 else 1
    tmp = [
        df_a.loc[date - pd.Timedelta(days=ndays):date - pd.Timedelta(days=1)], 
        group
    ]
    labels += chain.from_iterable([i] * len(chunk) for chunk in tmp)
    chunks += tmp

result = pd.concat(chunks).assign(group=labels)

print(result)
#            Type  Qty  group
# Date
# 2023-01-04    B    2      0
# 2023-12-29    A    1      1
# 2023-12-29    A    3      1
# 2023-12-30    A    2      1
# 2023-12-30    A    5      1
# 2023-12-31    A   10      1
# 2023-12-31    A    2      1
# 2024-01-01    B    2      1
# 2024-01-01    B    4      1
# 2024-01-01    B    3      1
# 2024-01-01    A    1      2
# 2024-01-02    B    5      2
# 2024-01-02    B    6      2
# 2024-01-03    B    1      3
```